# Apriori - Association Rule

Tags: python, apriori, market-basket-analysis

I have applied apriori to my frame matrix. However I get below rules that contains just one letter. Why rules just create one letter instead of a word?

```
frame_matrix:

     bazinda  yapilan  ragmen  yuklemesi   
  0    0        1        1       1                  
  1    0        0        1       0 
  2    2        0        0       1 

 rules = apriori(frame_matrix)   
 print "rules:", rules


 rules: ([[frozenset(['i'])], []], {frozenset(['f']): 0.12698412698412698, frozenset(['U']): 0.015873015873015872,
```